# Xcode: Undefined symbols in cpp protobuf when MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.8

Tags: xcode, macos, protocol-buffers

When I build [cpp protobuf](https://github.com/google/protobuf) with `MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.11`, then I add protobuf.a and includes in my project, it works fine.

but when I try to add to project protobuf.a which built with `MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.8', it generates errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "google::protobuf::MessageLite::ParseFromString(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)", "google::protobuf::MessageFactory::InternalRegisterGeneratedFile(char const*, void (*)(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&))",
  "google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream::WriteStringWithSizeToArray(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned char*)"
  "google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr::AssignWithDefault(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const*, google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr)"
  "google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::WriteStringMaybeAliased(int, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream*)", referenced from:
  ...
  ...
  ...
```

PS: My project builds with MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.8

How to build protobuf with MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.8?

Comment: Are you sure that's the only change?  It's more likely to be an issue relating to the different C++ runtime libraries (`libc++` vs `libstdc++`) being used.

Comment: yep, It's only one change which I made. When I repair MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET variable, it starts working

Comment: That's very unusual then.

Comment: When I build protobuf with MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.8, libprotobuf.dylib file depends on /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib. But all my project built using libc++

Comment: Saw it coming.  You're welcome.  However `libc++` is supported in 10.7+ so that 10.8 cut-off is wrong.